# Disable / Hide 14 Hyperthreaded Cores in Windows Task Manager

Tags: windows-10, cpu, cpu-usage, task-manager

Is there any way in Windows 10 to show only CPU usage for full cores?  It would be nice if Task Manager could do it, but another utility might be helpful as well.

The reason is really a matter of simplicity, being able to quickly glance at only full core usage, and taking less real estate on the screen.

It's only become annoying since I recently sold one of my children in order to buy a system with 14/28 cores/threads.  See image to get an idea.

[image]

Comment: Can Windows not just resize that display? I don't have a Win machine with enough cores to care about, but the Mac equivalent window just live resizes, from 'too small to actually see the lines properly', right up to full screen.  eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9nrq.png vs https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GIVm.png

Comment: @Tetsujin ya know that's a very good question, and would seem to be the right thing for Windows to do.  Unfortunately what you see above is the smallest possible size per core.  It doesn't scale dynamically at all, rather gives three size choices of small, medium, and large.  The image shows the smallest setting. I do miss my Macbook Pro a bit.

Comment: ahh... shame... I hope you didn't have to sell the Mac as well as the child... I mean, there's going too far ;)) [If you ever recant, there's always the old cheese grater... 12/24 cores. I'm filling the building with them as others sell them off. Can't beat 'em for price vs power right now.